# C# retrieve user feeds from facebook by application

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a Facebook application and I'm trying to use it to get the public post of one customer of mine from his wall (he has a personal Facebook account).

The application should work in background so I'm not able to use the user access token.

I'm using the facebook library [Facebook](http://facebooksdk.net/).

I got my app access token via

```
fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = MY_CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret = MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            });
```

After I got MY_APP_TOKEN, I have tried to get data via this apis, but they both return an empty array.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=feed&access_token=MY_APP_TOKEN
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts/?access_token=MY_APP_TOKE
```

When I try (the second one) with Sony I'm able to retrieve post from their pages. Is there some way to get public post of user wall?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed/#readperms

You'll need a User Access Token with `read_stream` permissions (which you probably won't get granted during app review).

> **Permissions:**
>
> - **Any valid access token** is required to view **public links**.
> - A user access token with **read_stream** permission is required.
> - Only posts whose authors have also granted read_stream permission to the app will be shown.

Comment: Thank your for your answer I gave the application the but i think I can't have one user access token.

Comment: Thank your for your answer I gave the application the read_stream permission but i think I can't have one user access token, because my application is a web application (rest webservice) that sould act like proxy to pass the facebook post to a mobile application. So this application can't expose the facebook login form because it is like a backend application.
According to this 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=it_IT#usertokens
I got there is no way to skip the facebook login form.
Am I right?
Thank you.